# Average time-series arrays of different length given the same timestamp in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, time-series, lodash

I would like to average several time-series arrays of different length using Javascript in an efficient manner.

- The reason for having different length is because some data is missing in some of the arrays.
- Time should be used as the common variable in all arrays for the average, i.e. you average the available values for a given timestamp.

For example:

```js
array1 = [[1, 100], [2, 200], [3, 300], [4, 400]];
array2 = [[1, 150], [3, 350], [4, 450]];
array3 = [[1, 250], [2, 350], [4, 450]];

allArrays = [array1, array2, array3];

// This is the result I would like to get, i.e. average of same timestamp 1, 2 .... n
average = [[1, 166.7], [2, 275], [3, 325], [4, 433]];
```

where each pair is `[time, value]`. Time is a number in Unix format.

My idea was to use *Lodash* to first convert the pairs to objects, then to group all equal timestamps and average the values. Then convert back to array.

```js
// Convert arrays to objects
for (int i = 0; allArrays.length; i++){
var array = allArrays[i];
allArrays[i] = toObject(array, ['time', 'value']);
}

// Group based on similar timestamp and average
???

// Convert averaged object to array
???

// Functions
function toObject(array, names){
  var obj = _.chain(array).map(function(p) {
    return _.zipObject(names, p)
}).value()
```

I am not a Javascript programmer and I would really appreciate any help on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using `lodash` you could use the following:

```js
const array1 = [
  [1, 100],
  [2, 200],
  [3, 300],
  [4, 400],
];
const array2 = [
  [1, 150],
  [3, 350],
  [4, 450],
];
const array3 = [
  [1, 250],
  [2, 350],
  [4, 450],
];

const groupedByTime = [...array1, ...array2, ...array3].reduce(
  (acc, [time, value]) => ((acc[time] ??= []).push(value), acc),
  {}
);
console.log("Grouped by time:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(groupedByTime, null, 4));
const result = Object.entries(groupedByTime).map(([time, values]) => [Number(time), (values.reduce((total, value) => (total += value), 0) / values.length).toFixed(1)]);
console.log("Result:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

```css
/* Stackoverflow: show only console */
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

### General idea

First you wanna group by time and then for each of the groupings calculate the average and bring it in the desired form. If required you can round the average using [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

### More detailed explanation

First you wanna create a flat array that contains all of the values by using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `[...array1, ...array2, ...array3]`. Then you use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group all values together that belong to the same time. I use a JavaScript object here and then [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) each value into the group as I encounter them.

Now it's about mapping the keys and values (= time and the values for that time) of that created JavaScript object, which we obtain by using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), to the expected result structure which is an array. But we also need to first compute the average. Again, we can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to sum up the group total and then divide by the number of elements in a group. If required we can use [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to round the result. By using the [Number constructor `Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number) I make sure that JavaScript treats the time as a `number`. This is also optional, but I think it makes sense since time especially in your case is a numeric value.

See also:

- [Nullish coalescing assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment)
- [Number constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number)

Comment: I like this answer because it is elegant, with minimal code. In addition, I liked your explanation. I learned several new things from Javascript and surprised with what you can do.


The number of arrays to average can change dynamically, therefore, I added this code


```let groupedByTime = [];
for (let i = 0; i < allArrays.length; i++){
groupedByTime.push(...allArrays[i])
}
```


Thanks everyone for the other answers too!

Comment: Glad you like it. For more elegance when you have an array of arrays you can use [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the array so `allArrays.flat().reduce(...`. In my code I could also have written `[array1, array2, array3].flat().reduce(...` which might be even nicer :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting arrays to objects and then back to arrays, you can directly calculate the averages while iterating through the arrays. Here's how you can do it:

```js
const array1 = [[1, 100], [2, 200], [3, 300], [4, 400]];
const array2 = [[1, 150], [3, 350], [4, 450]];
const array3 = [[1, 250], [2, 350], [4, 450]];

const allArrays = [array1, array2, array3];

const averageMap = new Map();

// Iterate through all arrays
for (const array of allArrays) {
  for (const [time, value] of array) {
    if (!averageMap.has(time)) {
      averageMap.set(time, { sum: value, count: 1 });
    } else {
      const existing = averageMap.get(time);
      averageMap.set(time, {
        sum: existing.sum + value,
        count: existing.count + 1,
      });
    }
  }
}

// Calculate averages and convert to array
const average = Array.from(averageMap.entries()).map(([time, data]) => [
  time,
  data.sum / data.count,
]);

console.log(average);
```

This code snippet will give you the desired average array:

```css
[
  [1, 166.66666666666666],
  [2, 275],
  [3, 325],
  [4, 433.3333333333333]
]
```

The code utilizes a 'Map' to keep track of the sum and count of values for each timestamp. It iterates through each array, updates the map with the sum and count, and then calculates the averages based on the accumulated sum and count. Finally, it converts the map back to the desired average array format.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array1 = [[1, 100], [2, 200], [3, 300], [4, 400]];
const array2 = [[1, 150], [3, 350], [4, 450]];
const array3 = [[1, 250], [2, 350], [4, 450]];

const allArrays = [array1, array2, array3];

// get largest id
const last = Math.max(...allArrays.map(arr => arr[arr.length-1][0]));
// convert arrays to objects so we can access values by id
const dicts = allArrays.map(arr => Object.fromEntries(arr));

const results = []
for (let i = 1; i <= last; i++) {
  let [count, sum] = dicts.reduce(
    (r,v) => (v[i] === undefined ? r : [r[0]+1, r[1] + v[i]])
    , [0,0]);
  results.push([i, sum / count]);
}

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the step wise process to achieve this, Initially you can just combine all those separate arrays into a single one with the help of [`Spread Syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and then iterate over it to create an object with the `timestamp` keys and array as a value and then finally calculate the average by iterating over the object based on the `keys`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const array1 = [[1, 100], [2, 200], [3, 300], [4, 400]];
const array2 = [[1, 150], [3, 350], [4, 450]];
const array3 = [[1, 250], [2, 350], [4, 450]];

const allArrays = [...array1, ...array2, ...array3];

const obj = {};
const average = [];

allArrays.forEach(([timestamp, value]) => {
  if (!obj[timestamp]) obj[timestamp] = []
  obj[timestamp].push(value)
});

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  const avg = calculateAverage(obj[key])
  average.push([Number(key), avg]);
})

function calculateAverage(array) {
  const sum = array.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
  const average = sum / array.length;
  return average;
}

console.log(average);
```

Answer (score 0):

An interesting case you have here. Seems that it's a job exactly for JS Map.

Here, take a look:

```
const array1 = [[1, 2], [2, 2]];
const array2 = [[3, 3], [1, 4]];
const resultMap = new Map();

// here we flatten arrays and iterate through the  resulting array
[...array1, ...array2].forEach(([time, value]) => {
   // and here we set the average value
   resultMap.set(time, resultMap.has(time) ? (resultMap.get(time) + value) / 2 : value);
});

console.log([ ...resultMap.entries() ]); // [ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 3, 3 ] ]
```

Comment: In this case the result will be the next:
`[ [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 2 ], [ 3, 3 ] ]`

Comment: This looks like a complicated way to avoid using [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: @Ouroborus , how would you use `.flatMap` in this case?

Comment: I retract my claim. Seems like it ends up being just as complicated.